# NSDictionary: fail to parse [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm having issue parsing a dictionary object returned in a json message from a webservice. The json is valid as AFNetworking is parsing it successfully. The actual response is below:

```
{
error = FALSE;
"error_desc" = "";
images =     (
            {
        hasItem = 0;
        image = "https://image/php4A6Xb8";
        imageGroupId = 28;
        "image_date" = "06/07/2014";
        "image_id" = 863;
        tag = "MCMOBILE-06072014-033902";
        thumb = "https://image/thumbs/php4A6Xb8";
    }
);
}
```

With this response my code does the following:

```
- (void) successResponseImages: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {

NSLog(@"Success: %@", dictionary);

NSString *error = [ dictionary objectForKey:@"error"];
NSString *errorDesc = [ dictionary objectForKey:@"error_desc"];
NSArray *images = [ dictionary objectForKey:@"images"];
....
```

At this point all values are correct and images is an array of 7 items.

i then try to loop through images using:

```
for (NSDictionary * image in images) {
                NSLog([image objectForKey:@"image_id"]); <<<<fail
                NSLog([image objectForKey:@"image"]);
                NSLog([image objectForKey:@"thumb"]);

            }
```

At fail it bombs out with the following error:

```
2014-07-06 15:44:19.161 mycobber[8976:60b] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ad2690
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.

EDIT: fuller stack trace

```
2014-07-06 15:44:19.292 mycobber[8976:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ad2690'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0214f1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01ece8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x021ec243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0213f50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0213f0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   CoreFoundation                      0x020cf89c CFStringGetLength + 140
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to NSLog is a format string, but your dictionary has a number set for its `@"image_id"` key. NSLog tries to treat this as a string by asking for its `length`, but this doesn't work because NSNumber has no such method. The format string to print a single object is `@"%@"`.

Answer (score 0):

cracked it:

`NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[image objectForKey:@"image_id"]]);`

Comment: NSLog takes arguments by default, there's no need for `stringWithFormat:`. Just put: 

`NSLog(@"%@", image[@"image_id"]);`. Short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct only. But your nslog statement is not correct and also no need to write stringwithformat as well just simply write like that below, it works -

```
    NSLog(@"%@",[image objectForKey:@"image_id"]);
```